# line of text goes to new line, instead of wrapping even with word-wrap:break-word

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Expected behavior: long line of text wraps to next line.
[image: text wraps before going to new line]

Actual behavior: Long line of text does not wrap and instead automatically goes to next line with no wrapping.

[image: text is not wrapping, just goes to new line]

Current HTML:

```
<p style="" class="subject">
     <span data-l10n-id="message-subject">Subject:</span>
     <span style="" class="detail">Re:jkla;sjdfkjasdf;jkasd;flkjasdf;kljasdf</span>
 </p>
```

The span with the class detail has the css style word-wrap:break-word.

Comment: add word-break: break-all;

Comment: Can you please create fiddle?

Comment: It is because there is no any space between the word. It is warp from space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some space between the word. Other wise it is counted as whole word.

```
<p style="" class="subject">
     <span data-l10n-id="message-subject">Subject:</span>
     <span style="" class="detail">Re: jkla; sjdfkjasdf; jkasd; flkjasdf; kljasdf</span>
 </p>

span{
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cu22yx7/)